# Go-sql-driver: Closing bad idle connection: connection reset by peer (mysql)

Tags: mysql, go

A go service usually get the error messages "closing bad idle connection: connection reset by peer"

```
Error log
[mysql] 2021/01/16 20:08:27 packets.go:122: closing bad idle connection: connection reset by peer
[mysql] 2021/01/16 20:13:27 packets.go:122: closing bad idle connection: connection reset by peer
```

Configuration

- Driver version: v1.5.0
- Go version: go1.15.6 darwin/amd64
- Server version: MySQL 5.7.29

Any idea, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database connection that remains open for a long time, you need to check the connection periodically.

```
func checkPing() {
   for {
     time.Sleep(time.Second * 15)
     err := DB.DB().Ping()
     if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
     }
   }
}
```